# PostgreSQL INSERT INTO - ON CONFLICT column name is ambiguous

Tags: postgresql, insert, conflict, ambiguous

I've seen questions with similar error messages, but could not find one with a problem like mine.
And to be more interesting, it seems like this is a PostgreSQL bug.
I can reproduce it any time.
I am using AWS Aurora PG 13.4

1. Create a table. Any table. My example was, let's say:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tbl1
(
    tblid bigint NOT NULL,
    val1 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT tbl1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (tblid)
)
```

2. Now create a function that inserts a record into that table, or updates on conflict, and then returns the records from the table. My example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_test(par_id bigint, par_v1 varchar)
returns table (tblid bigint, val1 varchar)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    insert into tbl1 (tblid, val1)
    values (par_id, par_v1)
    on conflict (tblid) do update set
        val1 = 'duplicate';
    
    return query
    select * from tbl1;
END;
$BODY$;
```

3. Now try to execute the function. For example:

```
select * from public.fn_test(1,'text1');
```

I always get an error stating the following:

```
ERROR:  column reference "tblid" is ambiguous
LINE 3:  on conflict (tblid) do update set
                     ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  insert into tbl1 (tblid, val1)
    values (par_id, par_v1)
    on conflict (tblid) do update set
        val1 = 'duplicate'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function fn_test(bigint,character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42702
```

4. Now the way I fix this, is that I can't have a column in the return table definition, that has the same name as the CONFLICT column. So in this case, in the return table definition, if we change the **tblid** column name into anything else, the function will work with no problem.

For example, if I change the function to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_test(par_id bigint, par_v1 varchar)
returns table (tblid1 bigint, val1 varchar)
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    insert into tbl1 (tblid, val1)
    values (par_id, par_v1)
    on conflict (tblid) do update set
        val1 = 'duplicate';
    
    return query
    select * from tbl1;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Function executes with no problems.
All I did is changed the **tblid** column name, in the return table definition, to **tblid1**.

5. So my question is: Why is this happening?

Comment: It is spelled out in the docs [Variable Substitution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST).

Comment: Would quoting the ambiguous reference help? Like `ON CONFLICT ("tblid") DO ...`

Comment: In order to understand the ambiguity here, it might help you to know that you can do things like `tblid := 1; val1 := 'one'; RETURN NEXT;` to add a row to the result of the function. So `tblid` isn't just "hidden" in the return type definition.